# Which drag and drop to use? jQuery draggable droppable or HTML5 native drag-and-drop? or maybe other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, drag-and-drop

We are developing a drag and drop CMS called ucraft.me. It is based on Laravel + EmberJS + jQuery + Greensock(GSAP).

Imagine it works the following way:

1. There is a blank page with a left panel, where you have different modules to craft your pages. Ex., title, button, image, slider, video, etc...
2. The white page is based on a grid where there can be max 4 modules.

Now imagine we have a module - button, in the centre of a full width row(span12) and now we decided to drop another module, like Title, which will split the current row into span6 - span6. Currently we are using jQuery draggable droppable, to calculate all the droppable areas and to let the user drop certain elements.

Can someone recommend a better drag and drop library to implement this, is there anyone with a similar experience? Do you think jQuery draggable-droppable is a good choice to implement the drag and drop feature in the site builder? Does it have good performance?

Or should we use HTML5 native drag-and-drop library?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This article may be of use: https://medium.com/delightful-ui-for-ember-apps/ember-js-and-html5-drag-and-drop-fa5dfe478a9a - leverage ember for the drag and drop events it provides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have read that before posting this question, to see others' point of view :)